# Rails 3 - Calculate model's attribute based on associated model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have three models - Usage(month, elec, gas), Project(project_type, date_implemented, manual_elec_savings, manual_gas_savings) and monthly_project_savings(elec, gas, usage_id, project_id).
The associations are set up as follows:

```
Project has_many :monthly_project_savings,
    has_many :usages, through :monthly_project_savings

Usage   has_many :monthly_project_savings
    has_many :projects, through :monthly_project_savings

monthly_project_saving belongs_to :usage, :project
```

I have a method in my Project model so that after a project is saved, it calculates the associated monthly_project_savings based on the project_type:

```
def calc_monthly_project_saving

//destroy all previous records
  self.monthly_project_saving.destroy_all

//calculate monthly savings
    Usage.all.each do |u|

    if self.project_type = "General" && self.date_implemented <= u.month
      self.monthly_project_savings.create(usage_id: u.id, elec: self.manual_elec_savings, gas: self.manual_gas_savings)
    elsif self.project_type="Elec" && self.date_implemented <= u.month
      self.monthly_project_savings.create(usage_id: u.id, elec: u.elec, gas:0)
    elsif self.project_type="Gas" && self.date_implemented <= u.month
      self.monthly_project_savings.create(usage_id: u.id, elec: 0, gas:u.gas)
    end
  end
end
```

I then call it using `after_save :calc_monthly_project_saving`.

My problem is that if I call the method using "after_save", the first if statement will always pass true, even if the project_type is different. As well as this, if I change the first `self.monthly_project_savings.create(elec:)` from `self.manual_elec_savings` to `u.elec`, then it returns monthly_project_savings as elec.

If I change it to call before_save, then it throws the error: `"You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"`, which makes sense. Although it will work this way when editing existing project records, but sometimes the date_implemented will change to "t" or "f". I have no idea how to do this, help??

Also as an aside, why does rails set the value of date_implemented to "f" if I call the method before_save when editing an existing record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My god! I spent a full day trying to figure out this problem....I solved it by changing the "=" in the if statements to "==". Feckin typos!